# Leaking information because of URL injection in php

Tags: php, html

This code leaks information from the login page when a route that does not exist is being tried to navigate at.

```php
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1> 
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  Name: <input type="text" name="uname">
  password: <input type="password" name="upass">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $loginusername = $_POST['uname'];
        $loginpassword = $_POST['upass'];
        if (empty($loginusername) || empty($loginpassword)) {
                echo "Please enter username and password";
        } else {
                $user = getEnv('USER');
                $password = getEnv('PASSWORD');
                $database = getEnv('DATABASE');
                $table = getEnv('SONGS');
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM $table where user_name = :username and password = :loginPassword";
                $statement = $db->prepare($query);
                $statement->bindParam(":username",$loginusername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam(":loginPassword",$loginpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                if(!$result) {
                        echo "<p>No result!</p>";
                        exit;
                } else {
                        $userid = $result[0][0];
                        $username = $result[0][1];
                }
        }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is an indexing page which will index all articles that are in the website.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="/">Return</a>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
        $file = $_GET['file'];  
        $file = file_get_contents($file);
        echo "$file";
        echo '<br /><a href="/myPage">Index</a>';
}
else {
        $user = getEnv('USER');
        $password = getEnv('PASSWORD');
        $database = getEnv('DATABASE');
        $table = getEnv('ARTICLES');
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt = $db->query($query);
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($stmt as $row) {
                $href = $row[2];
                $title = $row[1]; 
                echo "<li> <a href='/myPage?file=../dir/$href'>$title</a> </li> ";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When this href `echo "<li> <a href='/myPage?file=../dir/$href'>$title</a> </li> ";` is changed manually at browser at suppose this route `/myPage/?file=../login.php` it will cause to leak code from the login file, which can uncover to the attack some crucial information about my backend setup. Is there any way how to patch this problem.

Comment: Just make sure that there can be read only selected files, i.e. from public directory with .txt extension. However it's still quite weird approach.

Comment: Well, if a request to `/myPage/?file=../path/to/random/file.php` actually "leaks" the file, then put some checks into place. One way to do this is to use some sort of whitelist: Keep a list of files that the user is allowed to requests, and if the requested file is not in the list, then do not serve that file. As a general rule: When writing a backend you should always check whether such requests are legitimate. Otherwise you are opening up to a lot of potential security problems.

Comment: @biesior it is just for learning purpose, trying to patch bad code. Tried to google but did not find something specific for that and I am not very familiar with php best practices.

Comment: `getenv` is for Environmental Variables. Probably not what you want. In `file.php` test to see if the user is logged in. Make sure you keep your connection in a separate secure *(usually)* 700 folder. If the Client can send data to the Server page, that page can be accessed by any Client. `include` or `require` possibly `_once` the secure files into the Client accessible files.

Comment: What I'm trying to say (and others too) is that one of the best and easiest ways for avoiding data leaks is separating content files (or database rows) from executable code that can be hacked i.e. by writing them in `content` folder/table where only plain text or HTML can be stored. In your script when you read the `$_GET['file']` arg, just search for this file/row only in these *public content* locations, that way nobody will be able to read and crack your login page as it will be outside of allowed boundries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's easily avoided by sanitizing your input.
Structures such as this

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
        $file = $_GET['file'];  
        $file = file_get_contents($file);
```

are highly problematic.

But there isn't a one-size-fits-all solution without knowing what the legit files that you want to allow to be referenced are.

Roughly how many valid files are there ? are they all located in the same directory ? do they follow some sort of specific naming convention ? do they all have the same extension (or lack any at all) ?

---

Edit: I suspect you'll want something along these lines. I haven't tested it, so it's possible i made a typo somewhere, but it shouldn't suffer from the same vulnerabilities atleast.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="/">Return</a>
<?PHP

    $user     = getEnv('USER');
    $password = getEnv('PASSWORD');
    $database = getEnv('DATABASE');
    $table    = getEnv('ARTICLES');
    $db       = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
    $filekey  = 'ref';
    $dbcolumn = 'href'; // <--- should match the name of the column in mysql

    if (isset($_GET[$filekey]) && $request = $_GET[$filekey]) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT $dbcolumn FROM $table WHERE $dbcolumn = ?");
        $stmt->execute([ $request ]);
        if (  $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) 
        &&    !empty($records)
        &&    $record  = reset($records) 
        &&    isset($record[$dbcolumn]) 
        &&    $request = $record[$dbcolumn]
        ) {
            
            echo file_get_contents("../dir/$request");
            echo '<br /><a href="/myPage">Index</a>';
        
        } else {
            
            die('Access denied');
        
        }
        
        
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt  = $db->query($query);
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($stmt as $row) {
            $href  = $row[2];
            $title = $row[1]; 
            printf('<li><a href='/myPage?%s=%s'>%s</a></li>',
                $filekey,
                htmlentities($href,  ENT_QUOTES), 
                htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES)
            );
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you set $dbcolumn correctly (should match the mysql column name), and optionally change $filekey to whatever you want to see in the URL.

This fixes your security problem: it only allows filenames to be specified in the URL, that actually exist in your database table, so it cant be used to pull random files anymore. If someone tries to manually change thevalue in the URL to something not in the database they get the error above.

It also fixes potential problems with the title in the listing, which was being output raw (i added htmlentities). Depending on the type of content inside the files, you may want to wrap a htmlentities call around file_get_contents() aswell, but don't do that if there is actual html inside those files.

I did see some other oddities , such as that you create a prepared statement and then don't use it :) but that has no security implications in this case, i left it as is.

Comment: Well, there there are files that comes from the database, so it is not a static size. I limited to a certain type of files.

Comment: I see, but are the names of those files also present in the database then (or can they be infered from the data in the database) ? Actually, i get the gist now, looking back at the listing query. I'll type up a fix.

Comment: They get infered from the database.

Comment: I've added an updated version to the answer above.

Comment: for some reason I only get the access denied part, I do not understand where it fails to get the articles.